# FunctionImport throwing 500 internal error

Tags: objective-c, odata, sap-smp

We have an old application written in objective-c  using `SMP framework SMP 3.0 SP12`, and backend being `SAP SMP Odata services`, it's an offline based application but few functionalities only work in online mode. We are able to establish a connection successfully with the backend and login to the application.

After we are logged in we initiate various `POST/GET` requests either using the SMP framework `scheduleCreateEntity` offline method, and when the entity is saved in an offline DB we call - `(void) scheduleFlushQueuedRequestsWithDelegate:(id<SODataOfflineStoreFlushDelegate>) delegate;` requests to apply changes on backend services  OR  we can make request directly to onlineStore using `FunctionImports` methods. All the POST requests that we make using `scheduleCreateEntity` method are posted successfully, and we even receive correct responses back, similarly for `FunctionImports` most of them are working fine apart from a few calls, where we are receiving **500 internal server errors**.

We also tried connecting with a backend team, who can support us on this issue, and they confirmed that my request did reach SAP and response is a success at SAP end, but we never received that success response back in our application. What we received as a response is 500 internal server ERROR . I have shared payload request and FunctionImport syntax below-:

The functionImport syntax defined in SMP Framework looks like given below-:

```
/**
 * Schedule a FunctionImport
 * Supported return types are Entiy or EntitySet. Please check the metadata because e.g. Complex Type is an unsupported return type.
 * @param resourcePath the path of the resource with FunctionImport
 * @param options additional paramaters dictionary
 * @param completionBlock block called once execution completes; note that the completion block is redirected to the main UI thread
 */

- (id<SODataRequestExecution>) scheduleFunction:(NSString*)resourcePath
                                        options:(NSDictionary*)options
                                     completion:(void (^)(id<SODataRequestExecution> requestExecution, NSError *error))completionBlock;
```

Payload request to call FunctionImport which is failing is given below-:

```
-(void)sendRequestPostDatal:(Material*)mi
                       successBlock:(void (^)(id<SODataRequestExecution>))successBlock
                         errorBlock:(void (^)(NSError*))errorBlock{
  
    [self checkOpenOnlineStoreSuccessBlock:^{

      NSString * resourcePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"entity?parameter1='%@'&parameter2='%@'&parameter3='%@'&parameter4='%@'&parameter5=%ldm&parameter6='%@'&parameter7='%@'&parameter8='%@'", mi.value, mi.value, mi.value, mi.value, (long)mi.value, mi.value, mi.value, mi.value];


           [self.onlineStore scheduleFunction:resourcePath options:nil completion:^(id<SODataRequestExecution> requestExecution, NSError* error){
            if( error != nil ){
                [UtilityManager dismissLoadingAlert];
            }
           
            [self callResponse:requestExecution error:error successBlock:successBlock errorBlock:errorBlock];
        }];
    
    }];
    
}
```

I have removed real parameters value and properties from resourcePath, but the syntax remains the same.

Anyhelp would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: hmm internal server errors by accessing from outside is a bad sign that your code will ever solve SAP's issues. At least a server should answer a proper Server:Error:Code to act accordingly in offline mode.

Comment: your resourcePaths stringWithFormat at parameter5 is not a format expression. Instead it is a HEXDIG according to RFC3986. If this is causing the issues that is even worse because it means the receiver on server side is not properly decoding + parsing out malicious stuff.

Comment: @OlSen parameter 5 is actually an NSInteger value, so we are sending it with %ld prefix and the "m" that you see is required for SAP backend to understand it's a NSDecimal number  or integer value.